# Error in Pyinstaller when trying to convert py file?

Tags: python, error-handling, pygame, exe

I am trying to take a Python file and convert it to an exe file with Pyinstaller. However, when I do so, I get an error saying:

> Failed to execute python script.

Here is the pygame code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Auto Maze!")


myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 13)

x, y = 168, 100

gameover = False
gameover2 = False
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if gameover:
                if button1.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    gameover = False
                    gameover2 = gameover
                    x, y = 168, 100

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    """try:
assert player.colliderect(wall1)
except AssertionError:
pass
except NameError:
pass
else:
death_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
button1 = pygame.draw.rect(death_screen, (0, 0, 255), (200, 200, 30, 30))
if donk:
break"""
    if not gameover:
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if pressed[pygame.K_w]:
            y -= 5
        elif pressed[pygame.K_s]:
            y += 5
        elif pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            x -= 5
        elif pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            x += 5

        player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), (x, y, 60, 60))
        wall1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (400, 0, -150, 300))
        wall2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 150, 300))
        if player.colliderect(wall1):
            gameover = True
        elif player.colliderect(wall2):
            gameover = True
        else:
            gameover = False

    else:
        button1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), (175, 100, 60, 30))
        text = myfont.render("Try Again", False, (255, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(text, (176, 107 ))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

quit()
```

And here is what I typed to convert the file:

`pyinstaller --onefile -w "import pygame".py`

Also, if there are any better alternatives to Pyinstaller, please do tell me. I've heard that Pyinstaller is not the best.

My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: `pyinstaller --onefile -w your_file.py`

Comment: In my file name, there is no underscore, however. I tried this and it said the file was not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point pyinstaller to your .py file, not the first line of your .py file.
For example if your file is called example.py, you need to write

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w example.py
```

Comment: My python file is called import pygame.py

Comment: That is the literal name of my file

Comment: then you should call ```pyinstaller --onefile -w "import pygame.py"```